# Background-image resize after window-size

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

I'm pretty new to web-development and web-design, and I'm working on a website for a company right now(www.momentium.no). They want to have the background image(s) at the top recognize the browsers window-size, so that the image(s) fills the whole screen and don't show the content below before you scroll down when you load the website.

Could anyone of you check this out? Would be great to get a little bit of help!

Thanks,
Yngvar

Comment: Can we see some of your code?

Comment: depending on browser compatibility you could have a look at the css3 property background-size

Comment: view-source:http://momentium.no/ 

It's in the first div with the id "background-image". Tried to copy it in here, but it was a mess!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the height to 100% using CSS will work, but you'll have to revise your HTML structure in order to maintain it's flow when the window is resized.

Otherwise, you can try the following code snippets:

**JS:**

```
var $imageWrapper = $('#background-image'),
    $contentSpacer = $('section#wrapper > header'),

    // Some buffer value, adjust this to get the rest of the content aligned properly
    buffer = 200;

// Set the div height on pageload
$(document).ready(function() {
   var windowHeight = $(window).height();

   $imageWrapper.height( windowHeight );
   $contentSpacer.height( windowHeight );
});

// Change the div height on window resize
$(window).resize(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      thisHeight = $this.height();

  // Set the height of the image container to the window height
  $imageWrapper.height( thisHeight );
  $contentSpacer.height( thisHeight - buffer );
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#background-image {
  background-size: cover;

  // Change this to the minimum height your page will support
  min-height: 600px;
}
```

The rest of the code you have seems correct, so adding these should fix things up. A couple of things to keep in mind here:

- The JS isn't placing any limitation on the height being applied here, so the CSS will still apply even if the window is resized to 10px height. Most designs have a minimum height/width before breaking, so using a `min-height` on your `#background-image` div might be a good idea.
- Check the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size) before implementing, if you need to support one of the unsupported browsers, you'll need to either write a fallback or restructure your code in such a way that it degrades gracefully. IE9+, Chrome21+ and FF26+ should be good enough though.
- Looks like you're using a spacer in the main section to ensure that the page content comes in after the main slider. The structure of the page can be modified so that you don't have to modify two element heights. As I mentioned at the beginning, you can probably use the pure CSS solution if you restructure.

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 solutions :

- As Pete says, you can use "background-size" css3, but it will not be compatible for older browser
- You can use javascript with `$(window).height()` and `$(window).width`

Answer (score 0):

The Only Way is create a repponsive design for your company..all the problem will be solved by responsive design...

- Change the image size depends upon the browser window size Other wise
- change the image to another one also possible

Comment: That was very un-constructive! For BS like this feel free to use comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height of your "background-image" div to 100%, it will work.

Check this code:

```
#background-image {
width: 100%;
height: 100% !important;
position: absolute !important;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
background: #000;
}
```